# Shortcut in Visual Studio to toggle between one and multiple lines of code

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there any shortcut in Visual Studio for the following scenario(s)?
**1) Toggle between this**

```
public int MyProperty
{
   get;
   set;
}
```

and this

```
public int MyProperty { get; set; }
```

**2) Toggle between this**

```
if (number > 0)
{
   number++;
}
```

and this

```
if (number > 0) { number++; }
```

Answer (score 0):

To format your code use CTRL + E + D. If you want special formating, you can check options in this place : Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Formatting->New Lines. There are all of possible options for this.

Comment: Ctrl + E + D is already heavily used by me ;) Your suggestion is helpful but doesn't allow any toggling so I guess the answer to the question is no.